# DIY skylight sun-block, fire hazard?

Tags: skylight

We have two skylights in our master bedroom that get quite a bit of light during the day.  Normally this wouldn't bother us, but we have a one-month old now sharing the room with us that gets enamored with the light coming from it at 6 AM, making it very difficult to get her back to sleep.  I picked up two black foam boards from CVS and put them up to block the sun.  It works, but I wanted to make sure this is not a fire hazard.  I'm open to other affordable suggestions.  Just fyi: the house is 40' high, so getting to the roof and doing something on the outside of the skylight is a little beyond my capabilities right now as I don't have the appropriate equipment.

Question is: are these foam boards a fire hazard if they see sunlight for long periods of time?  Pics below.

The make shift sun-block using black foam boards:
[image]

Skylight without the boards
[image]

Comment: Probably not a fire hazard, but black absorbs light while white reflects it. Black foam board would be more likely to warp due to he heat and fall out after a while. If it’s cheap and easy, white foam board is probably the better way to go.

Comment: @statueuphemism thanks! I'll head to CVS to see if they have a white board. You can tell the board is already beginning to warp

Comment: @statueuphemism could I accomplish the same effect if I cover the black boards with white sheets of normal paper?

Comment: Should be the same effect. Jack’s solution is definitely cleaner and the black foam may work for a good while yet—probably long enough for your newborn to be sleeping in his/her own room (don’t wait until he/she is 23 ;-D I just had my second child and we started him out in his own crib in his own room based on the experience from transitioning our first).

Comment: @statueuphemism exactly! I just need a solution for another 5 months until she’s 6mo, then she moves to her own room. I’ll give it a shot and hope it doesn’t warp too much. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you placed a thermometer to see what the temp is?  I can't imagine it would be hot enough up there to cause any problems. It's no different than any large window with dark drapes or blinds closed and sun shining through.

There is a nice lip on that crown molding that would be perfect to hold a pull down,sun blocking shade.

Comment: True - I doubt it gets that hot. Probably not more than 80F.  I guess I wasn't sure if direct sunlight on it would make things worse (I'm thinking back to childhood where you can start a fire with a magnifying glass deflecting the sun... It's not that hot outside but it can still ignite, I think?)

Comment: I'm not finding any affordable pull down shades on home depot's site. They're all in the $100+ ballpark.

Comment: @David  I had something similar and got a white, spring roll standard shade.  I mounted it in the opening, got some white twine, a pulley and a cleat.